# Object of type is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter

There is a state class

```
  Isolate isolate;

  static void runIsolate(SendPort sendPort) {
    stdout.write('isolate run');
    locator<LocalStorageService>().makeSalt(); // error
    ...
  }
```

The error arrives when I call locator()

```
E/flutter (32123): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(864)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (32123): Exception: Object of type LocalStorageService is not registered inside GetIt
E/flutter (32123): #0      GetIt.get (package:get_it/get_it.dart:30:9)
E/flutter (32123): #1      GetIt.call (package:get_it/get_it.dart:41:12)
E/flutter (32123): #2      _SignUpFormState.runIsolate (package:mysuperapp/forms/sign_up_form/sign_up_form.dart:154:12)
```

where LocalStorageService is described as

```
GetIt locator = GetIt();

class LocalStorageService {
  static LocalStorageService _instance;

  static Future<LocalStorageService> getInstance() async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = LocalStorageService();
    }

    return _instance;
  }
  ...
```

Why the error arrives inside the static method? It works in regular function inside state class.

Comment: `locator.registerSingleton<LocalStorageService>(LocalStorageService());`

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu my code already uses it

Comment: definitely your code doesn’t use it, there is no such line in your code

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu why then locator founds LocalStorageService in regular function inside the state class?

Comment: I don't see any `regular function inside the state class` in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to using an `Isolate` as Isolates can not share memory with other threads. This means your call to `locator` is not finding the instance you created previously which had LocalStorageService registered, it's looking at a new instance where LocalStorageService hasn't been registered.

This effectively means you can't use GetIt's Singleton pattern inside an `Isolate` as this requires memory sharing.